# Stream video from python code(ffmpeg)

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, video-streaming

I have video frames from  below  code

```
(grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
```

Now I want to stream this live video from my python code.

I plan on using `ffmpeg` but please do tell me if I can do this with another tool.

I have tried this but didn't work:

```
subprocess.call(["ffmpeg", "-f", "rawvideo", "-pixel_format", "bgr24", "-video_size", "544x576", "-framerate", "25", "-i", "-", "http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm"], stdin=frame.tostring())
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below, it works -

```
subprocess.call(["ffmpeg", "-f", "/dev/videp.mp4", "-pixel_format", "bgr24", "-video_size", "544x576", "-framerate", "25", "-i", "-", "http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm"]);
```